# How do i switch the button icon from nightmode to day mode?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

In the below code I have linked some js/jQuery to elements in my html which should be self explanatory. I have console logged each if else statement to see what the issue is and it seems to be stuck on the first if statement.

```js
function toggleDisplay() {
var icon = document.getElementById("togglebutton");
var night_icon = 'assets/Feed_Toggle_Night.png'
var day_icon = 'assets/Feed_Toggle_Day.png'
$("displaytog").on("click", () => {
    if (icon.src == night_icon) {
        icon.src = day_icon;
        console.log("success1");
    }else {
        icon.src = night_icon;
        console.log("success2");
    }
})
}
toggleDisplay();
```

```html
<displaytog>
  <img src="assets/Feed_Toggle_Night.png" id="togglebutton"/>
</displaytog>
```

Comment: Maybe you need `==` or `===` i.e. comparison operator instead of assignment operator `=` in your if condition.

Comment: upon changing the first if statement to the comparrison operator you mentioned only the else statement will execute regardless of what the src equals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning `icon.src` to `night_icon` by accident. change your condition to check if they include any of your paths. the reason you need to use `includes` is because the src is a full path while your conditions are using relative paths. The src looks like this - `"https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/assets/Feed_Toggle_Day.png"`

```
 if (icon.src.includes(night_icon))
```

Comment: i changed the if statement like so but now only the else statement is executing

Comment: please paste the while code again...

Comment: re-edited code above

Comment: I modified my answer so it will work. please check it now.

Comment: absolute legend. marked your answer as correct thankyou

Comment: you are welcome my friend. I would also appreciate if you can upvote the answer